# Projectile Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I've spent some time pondering the answer to this equation, without any success.

A cannon is arranged to fire projectiles, with initial speed $v_0$, directly up the face of a hill of elevation angle $\alpha$. At what angle from the horizontal should the cannon be aimed to obtain the maximum possible range $R$ up the face of the hill?

So my work is as follows:

$x = (v_0  \cos\theta) t $

$y = (v_0  \sin\theta) t - 0.5gt^2$

I then set up an expression for $y$ substituting ${x\over v_0  \cos\theta}$ for $t$

I don't know what to do after this.

I also have $\tan^{-1}(h/a) = \alpha$

I am having trouble seeing how to incorporate the fact that the ground is not flat. If the ground was flat I would be almost there but I just don't see how to use the slope. Could someone please give me a detailed explanation for the problem?

Comment: 45 degrees... idk why

Comment: posting an answer now

Comment: because I just did some research

Comment: express the slope as a straight line, that is a relationship between $x$ and $y$, in the form $y=mx$. Then find the point of intersection of the trajectory and this line by solving the simultaneous equations involving $x$ and $y$. You should get the point as a function of the angles, and so you also have the length from the origin to this point.  Then maximise this length varying theta but  keeping alpha constant, either by calculus or maximising the trig functions (eg max $\sin\theta$ is 1, when $\theta=\pi/2$.